# Regarding Android Studio install type options

Tags: java, android-studio, installation, sdk

I am a beginner at programmming in Java and am currently setting up Android Studio o my PC. The setup process involves choosing between standard and custom install types and I am confused between the two. Please explain in detail the purpose / features / pros and cons of both installation types.

I tried asking a query regarding installation of an environment and SDK.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.